# Proof of $\bf y$ with $\mathbf{Ay}=\mathbf{w}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given $\mathbf A$ is an $m×m$ matrix. Suppose that for any $m×1$ matrices $\bf u$ and $\bf v$, if
>   $\mathbf{Au}=\mathbf{Av}$, then $\mathbf u=\mathbf v$. Prove that for each $m×1$ matrix $\mathbf w$, there exists an $\mathbf m×1$ matrix $\bf y$ such that $\mathbf {Ay}=\mathbf w$.

I understand that $\mathbf{Au}=\mathbf{Av}\implies\mathbf A(\mathbf u-\mathbf v)=\mathbf0$, which implies that $\mathbf {Ax}=\mathbf 0$ having only trivial solution. From here on, I do not know how to address the question. Should we take $\mathbf w$ as $\binom00$, for $m$ columns? Should we equate $\mathbf y=\mathbf u-\mathbf v$?

I do not understand the concepts from this point. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is not $|A|\ne 0?$ Doesn't this mean the linear system $Ax=y$ has a unique solution?

Comment: hmm, mind elaborating?

Comment: The conditions imply that $A$ is invertible, so choose $ y = A^{-1} w$.

Comment: @copper.hat Which conditions imply that A is invertible?

Comment: @KelvinLim: The square matrix $A$ is invertible **iff** it is injective **iff** it is surjective. This is of major importance with linear systems. In your case, you have that $Ax=Ay$ implies $x=y$ which means $A$ is injective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $\mathbf u,\mathbf v, A\mathbf u = A\mathbf v \implies \mathbf u=\mathbf v$

$A$ is injective.

$A$ has an inverse.

$w = A^{-1} y$

Comment: Why $u\ne v\implies Au\ne Av?$

Comment: That is not my problem, I do have other problems with this proof, (which I am working on)  but it is the contrapostive of the statement above it.

Comment: I didn't say it's your problem. I only think it is something you must clarify in your answer.